# How To Display Author Popup on Entry Meta (Genesis Framework)?

Tags: functions, jquery, javascript, post-meta, author

How to when the mouse pointer on the author name can display Author Popup like this site?

```
https://www.dietdoctor.com/low-carb/keto
```

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Genesis doesn't have built-in popup styling like (for example) bootstrap etc.
You will have to find an extension plugin or built it custom.

Take a look at this tutorial to start with CSS tooltips:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp